# Wordpress posts go to homepage

Tags: wordpress

When you go to a post page - such as: http://www.faithsheridan.com/mydesignblog/ideas-and-inspirations/dreaming-of-color-and-updates-on-my-patio/

What you see is the same as the main blog homepage: http://www.faithsheridan.com/mydesignblog/.

What's going on?

Comment: can u explain more wht r u trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a **single.php** in your theme, and you've setup your permalinks in the backend properly (Settings -> Permalinks).